# Replacing single elment if a 2D list made with `For loop` vs made by element multiplication in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

Let say I wanted a list with all zeros of 5x3 (row x column). I can make the list in 2 ways

1. Using for loop:

```
a = []   # My 2D list (currently empty)
for i in range(5):
    thisele = []
    for j in range(3):
        thisele.append(0)
    a.append(thisele)
```

2. Using element multiplication method which I recently learnt

```
a = [[0]*3]*5
```

Now both genertes the same 2D list which looks like this

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

Now I want to replace an element in the third column at first row with 11 so I used the following line
`a[0][2] = 11`

This gives 2 different results based on the technique used.
The first technique gives:

```
[0, 0, 11]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

and the second technique gives:

```
[0, 0, 11]
[0, 0, 11]
[0, 0, 11]
[0, 0, 11]
[0, 0, 11]
```

The second result is clearly undesirable as thats not what I intended to do.
Can someone explain why the results vary in the second case and if it's a bug or a feature.

If its a feature then in what scenario can the second method be implemented

Comment: `a = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(5)]` is the terse way to avoid making shallow copies, but see above links for more details

Comment: Thankyou, this was helpful